# Delete block of text before saving output in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to delete a block of text before saving the output. Its a batch script. There is a lot of unnecessary data that needs to be deleted from the output. I am using `findstr /v` to delete the matched text but unfortunately not able to receive the required output.

Current output:

> shdgs - Copyright (c) 1989-2006 hsagd asjgdjasgd and/or hsgdhgas. All
>   Rights Reserved. hashjasdsadasdasd on Mon 10/24/2016 07:53
>
> [hjasgdjaghsdh...] ajsgdjasgdajs: 
>       jasdjkasjdkhasjkh: C:\test\test\test\lic.dat:
>
> jasbdjadsb: sadfsadfsdfadfsadf
>
> Vendor daemon status (on asdasad):
>
> ```
>  sadfsadf: UP v10.8
> ```
>
> Users of 259:  (Total of 8 licenses issued;  Total of 4 licenses in
>   use)
>
> "259" v5.8, vendor: ptc_d   floating license
>
> ```
> 876347634 dfdhgdhf khdskhf (v7.0) (sdfsdf/6784 601), start Mon 10/24 6:42
> abcd sdsdfsfd gfdfgdd (v7.0) (fdgdfgdf/6554 211), start Mon 10/24 6:02
> ```

I require to remove only the following text:

> shdgs - Copyright (c) 1989-2006 hsagd asjgdjasgd and/or hsgdhgas. All
>   Rights Reserved. hashjasdsadasdasd on Mon 10/24/2016 07:53
>
> [hjasgdjaghsdh...] ajsgdjasgdajs: 
>       jasdjkasjdkhasjkh: C:\test\test\test\lic.dat:
>
> jasbdjadsb: sadfsadfsdfadfsadf
>
> Vendor daemon status (on asdasad):
>
> ```
>  sadfsadf: UP v10.8
> ```

Final output:

> Users of 259:  (Total of 8 licenses issued;  Total of 4 licenses in
>   use)
>
> "259" v5.8, vendor: ptc_d   floating license
>
> ```
> 876347634 dfdhgdhf khdskhf (v7.0) (sdfsdf/6784 601), start Mon 10/24 6:42
> abcd sdsdfsfd gfdfgdd (v7.0) (fdgdfgdf/6554 211), start Mon 10/24 6:02
> ```

How can we efficiently remove the selected text?

Thanks.

Comment: `findstr /r "license v7.0" test.txt`

Comment: Is the text in a file, or command output? Are the top lines the same quantity every time? You can use `for /f` to skip lines at the top. Do the lines you want have something unique that you can search for? Why isn't `findstr /v` working?

Comment: What have you tried on your own? Please share your efforts! Otherwise this is not a real question but a task request, which is off-topic here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon at least some of your text being real:

```bat
@Echo Off

(Set SrcFile=C:\test\test\test\lic.dat)
(Set DstFile=C:\test\test\test\fixedlic.dat)

Set "LNR="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr/BNC:"Users of " "%SrcFile%"') Do (
    If Not Defined LNR Set "LNR=%%A")
Set/A LNR-=1
More +%LNR% "%SrcFile%">"%DstFile%"
```

Just change the paths within the parentheses on lines 3 & 4 to suit your purposes.

If you wish to **Rename** the **"%DstFile"** to **"%SrcFile%"** on a new last line then feel free to do so.